Iterate forwards or backwards depending on order of iterators
I have an std::vector with entries, and two entries a and b that are guaranteed to be in that vector. I'm using std::find to get iterators aIt and bIt in the vector for a and b. But I don't know which of a and b comes first in the vector. Now I want to   do something with all entries from a to b, for which I need to iterate from a to b, regardless of the order of these two. How can that be done ?
The conventional iterator comparison won't work if a comes after b in the vector:

std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
auto aIt = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a);
auto bIt = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), b);
for (; aIt != bIt; aIt++) {
  std::cout << *aIt << std::endl;
}

Output:
5
0
1041
0
825494064
909128761
2609
0
0
0
0
0
[...]
0
0
0
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Since aIt and bIt both reference elements of the same vector, aIt < bIt will check if a comes before b.    If what you are doing is of the form some_operation(start, end) you can therefore do something like if (aIt < bIt) some_operation(aIt, bIt); else some_operation(bIt, aIt);.    Personally, I would not assume that both a and b are in the vector (too easy for code to change the vector) so would check for end iterators before doing that.

"The conventional iterator comparison won't work if a comes after b in the vector:" -- No, the comparison works fine. It's the logic that problematic. However, if you want to blame an expression, I'd go with the increment, since that cannot get you from where you start to where you want to go.

"all entries from a to b" -- Does order matter? "From a to b" suggests to me that the loop should start at a and proceed from there in reverse order to b. If order doesn't matter, then "between a and b (including one endpoint)" would better describe the situation. Or maybe order matters and the order should be from low/early indices to high/later indices? That could be captured as "from the earlier of a and b to the later".

Because you are using a std::vector, you can just compare aIt and bIt and swap them if they are out of order.
if (aIt > bIt)
  std::swap(aIt, bIt);
for (; aIt != bIt; aIt++) {
  std::cout << *aIt << std::endl;


You can use std::minmax in conjunction with std::ranges::subrange (instead of manually advancing the iterators).
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int a = 5, b = 2;
    auto [startIt, endIt] = std::minmax({std::ranges::find(vec, a), std::ranges::find(vec, b)});
    for (const auto& x : std::ranges::subrange(startIt, endIt))
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}


If ---a---b--- then bIt is not vec.end(). If ---b---a--- then bIt is vec.end() and bIt gets aIt and aIt searches for b, suitable to any container:
auto aIt = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a);
auto bIt = std::find(aIt, vec.end(), b);
if (bIt == vec.end())
  bIt = std::exchange(aIt, std::find(vec.begin(), aIt, b));

